# Background image randomly changed when scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

1) I'm wondering that my background of TextView shuffling when i scrolls downwards or upwards, I created `CardView` using `RecyclerView`. This is my custom adapter

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {


public static List<Myitems_item> my_items ;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Myitems_item> my_items) {

    this.context = context;
    this.my_items = my_items;
}


@Override
public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.innercard_size_selection, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    final Myitems to_off = my_items.get(i);

    viewHolder.productSize.setText(Double.toString(to_off.getNumber()));

    viewHolder.to_offer = to_off;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return my_items.size();
}

// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView productSize;

    public Myitems_item to_offer;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        productSize =TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.productSize);

        productSize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                productSize.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focus_shape);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Any idea how to fix it? why it happen when it scrolling.

2) how can i get single selection mode in recyclerview. [I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0sru.png) I mean I want to create like RadioGroup as recyclerview

Comment: Where is your `ImageView`?

Comment: sory not image background of textview.edited my question.Thank for your replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model class (Myitems_item), you need to have some boolean say 'isSelected' which keeps track of selected/unselected cases. And then in your onBindViewHolder() method, you need to check if the item in the current position is selected or not and set background accordingly.

For your second issue, you will have to first set a border for your item view with something like below code (set the below drawable as item background).

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

And then apply the same logic for your first question. 
You need to have a boolean in your model to keep track of item selection.
When user clicks on an item, set its background to the above drawable and set the boolean for that model item as true.
Then when the user clicks on the next item, set the boolean for the previous item as false and current item as true and then notify the adapter.

I hope you got my point.

Comment: @jayakristnanSalim thank you solved my first issue.is there any idea about my 2nd questoin

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by single selection more. Usually if you have set click listeners in ViewHolder class, you will get call back in onClick() method. If the adapter position is what you are looking for then you can get it using getAdapterPosition() method inside ViewHolder class.

Comment: I guess you have a recyclerview with a horizontal layout and when user clicks on an item, you are highlighting it. But when you touch another item, that is also getting highlighted. Is this your problem?

Comment: please tell me how can i get previous selected item

Comment: Just save the adapter position no in some variable say 'int previousSelectedPosition'.

This is purely your logic to keep track of things.

Comment: @jayakristnanSalim finally my issues are solved.Thank for your support bro

Answer (score 0):

Hey I use below code in my application,

Try this code.

If this code will work I will explain this code.

Try and let me know if any issue.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static List<Myitems_item> my_items ;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Myitems_item> my_items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_items = my_items;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.innercard_size_selection, false);
        // create ViewHolder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final Myitems to_off = my_items.get(i);
        viewHolder.productSize.setText(Double.toString(to_off.getNumber()));
        viewHolder.to_offer = to_off;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_items.size();
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView productSize;
        public Myitems_item to_offer;
        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView){
            super(itemLayoutView);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
            productSize = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.productSize);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            productSize.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focus_shape);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working same issue(background randomly changed).textview background changed OnClickListener but when scrolling in RecyclerView it changed randomly

Comment: thank you finally i solved my issue using jayakristnanSalim suggestion. is there any idea about my 2nd question

Comment: I can't understand your second question. Please explain more.